# Error in nested template argument when compile c++ in unix

Tags: c++, unix, g++

I just wrote a cpp file in unix.
I have bunches of codes that use nested template argument.
For example:

```
void showAlb(map<string, vector<string>> mapArt, map<string, vector<string>> mapSong, vector<string> artists, int artnumb);
```

However I always got error
`

> error: ?>?should be ? >?within a nested template argument list

`

```
 void showAlb(map<string, vector<string>> mapArt, map<string, vector<string>> mapSong, vector<string> artists, int artnumb);`
                                   ^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, you would probably like to use C++11.  Assuming a recent enough version of g++, you can compile using C++11 rules by adding `-std=c++11` to the compilation command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-C++11, nested template arguments had to have a space between the two closing angle brackets:

```
map<string, vector<string> >
//                    here^
```

C++11 allows you to omit that space. If you're stuck with C++03, just make sure you follow that particular syntax rule.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to fix this. You can either switch to C++11, where this is supported as is, or you can do what the error message is telling you to do:

```
void showAlb(map<string, vector<string>> mapArt, map<string, vector<string>> mapSong, vector<string> artists, int artnumb);
```

Should be:

```
void showAlb(map<string, vector<string> > mapArt, map<string, vector<string> > mapSong, vector<string> artists, int artnumb);
```

Notice the extra spaces.

The reason for this strange behavior is that `>>` is an operator of its own. The C++ parser first pass (i.e. - the lexical analysis) parses this as that operator, rather than two `>`. This means that the context free parsing has nothing to work with when searching for the terminating angular brackets.

The problem was so common, that C++11 added an explicit rule to allow this. The compiler understands that, and gives you an excellent error message.

Comment: Thank you, it is really help.